# Solving a Linear Diophantine Equation

Tags: number-theory

A Linear Diophantine Equation is of the following form:
                                                                                       $Ax+By+C=0$, where $x_1 \leq x \leq x_2$ and $y_1 \leq y \leq y_2$.

If the value of $A,B,C,x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ are given and $x_1 \leq x_2$ and $y_1 \leq y_2$, then how many solutions can be found? How can I find out the total number of solutions according to the above condition.

Answer (score 1):

In order that a solution exists we must have $\gcd(A,B)\mid C$.

Assuming that $\gcd(A,B)=1$ and $(x_0,y_0)$ is a solution of the diophantine equation, *every* solution is of the form

$$(x_0-kB,x_0+kA),\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}\tag{1}$$
hence it is sufficient to count for how many values of $k$ the LHS of $(1)$ belongs to $[x_1,x_2]\times [y_1,y_2]$. A trivial upper bound for the number of solutions is given by:
$$ N\leq\min\left(\left|\frac{x_2-x_1}{B}\right|,\left|\frac{y_2-y_1}{A}\right|\right).\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

We are assuming that $A, B \gt 0$ to simplify things a little.
$$
Ax + By + C = 0 \\
\gcd(A, B) = d
$$
Of course, $d \mid c$ or else there are no solutions. We can write
$$
A = da \\
B = db
$$
After finding a solution $x_0, y_0$ to the equation, all other solutions can be given by
$$
x = x_0 + bt \\
y = y_0 - at \\
\forall t \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Putting these values into the given inequalities,
$$
x_1 \leq x \leq x_2 \\
x_1 \leq x_0 + bt \leq x_2 \\
\frac{x_1 - x_0}{b} \leq t \leq \frac{x_2 - x_0}{b}
$$
and similarly (note that the inequality is reversed because we are dividing by a negative number):
$$
\frac{y_1 - y_0}{-a} \geq t \geq \frac{y_2 - y_0}{-a}
$$
Combining the two, we get
$$
\max(\frac{x_1 - x_0}{b}, \frac{y_2 - y_0}{-a}) \leq t \leq \min(\frac{x_2 - x_0}{b}, \frac{y_1 - y_0}{-a})
$$
Now finding the number of integers $t$ that satisfy this inequality is easy.

Comment: I can't understand the part:x=x0+bt,y=y0-at .How is it possible.However,why we consider min(x1−x0b,y2−y0−a)≤t≤min(x2−x0b,y1−y0−a) instead of x1−x0b≤t≤x2−x0b or y1−y0−a≥t≥y2−y0−a to fix up the value of t

Comment: We know that $(x_0, y_0)$ is a solution. Now, if you expand $A(x_0 + bt) + B(y_0 - at)$ you will see that it evaluates to $C$.

Also, we take the minimum and maximums because we want $t$ to satisfy both conditions at the same time, so we are merely combining two inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

ax+by=c
implies ax=c(mod b)
implies x=c*{a^-1}(mod b)=c+(a^-1 mod b) + bt, for a parametrically chosen constant t,
and y=(c-ax)/b.

Now provided the numbers, you can crunch through, setup and inequality chain with x and y, and solve.