# Extended Euclid Algorithm

Tags: number-theory

A Linear Diophantine Equation is of the following form: $Ax+By+C=0$, where $x_1\le x\le x_2$ and $y_1\le y\le y_2$.

If the value of $A$, $B$, $C$, $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, $y_2$ are given and $x_1\le x_2$ and $y_1\le y_2$, then how many solutions can be found? 
How can I find out the total number of solutions according to the above condition?

I asked the above question in this link:[Solving a Linear Diophantine Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959029/solving-a-linear-diophantine-equation)
before. But there I didn't give sample input and output.
I liked the second answer in the above link but when I checked the  sample input and output
according to the second answer it gives me wrong result

It is worthy of mention that the reasoning of the second answer based on $A$, $B\gt 0$, but my question is that what I have to do if $A$, $B\lt 0$ and how will I match sample input and output using the given answer.

Here, I have included sample input and output: 
[image]

I need a method that satisfies the above input and output. I also need better explanation of the method with example.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not too hard. 
You have $Ax + By + C = 0$ which is equivalent to $Ax + By = -C$ this has a solution if and only if $ gcd(A,B) \lvert C$ then to find a solution you use the Euclidean algorithm and you express the $gcd(A,B)=d$ as a linear combination of $A$ and $B$. This gives you some $ s,t \in \mathcal{Z}$ such that $As + Bt = d$. Now as $d$ divides $C$ then $C = dh$ for some integer $h$. Then you multiply $ s$ and $t$ by h and you have a solution, only one. To find all, just solve the homogeneous equation $Az + Bw = 0$. Clearly the solutions are $ z = -Bn \wedge w = An, \forall n \in \mathcal{Z}$. Now all the solutions are $ x = sh -Bn \wedge y = th + An, \forall n \in \mathcal{Z}$.